# How do I access a variable from a second class in Java?

Tags: java, android, variables, object, static

I'm trying to generate a certain number of buttons depending on the amount of players. However, whenever I try to move the number of players from one class to another, the app crashes.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText[] playersEditText = new EditText[10];

    public static Player[] players = new Player[10];
    public static int playerCount = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        playersEditText[0] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player0);
        playersEditText[1] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player1);
        playersEditText[2] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player2);
        playersEditText[3] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player3);
        playersEditText[4] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player4);
        playersEditText[5] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player5);
        playersEditText[6] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player6);
        playersEditText[7] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player7);
        playersEditText[8] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player8);
        playersEditText[9] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player9);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                playerCount = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    String name = playersEditText[i].getText().toString();

                    if (!(name.equals(""))) {
                        playerCount++;
                        players[playerCount] = new Player(name);
                    }
                }

                if (playerCount < 5)
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You need at least 5 players " + playerCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlayerRevealment.class));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Above is the Main Activity. I'm trying to access the object players and the int playerCount in the following class.

```
public class PlayerRevealment extends AppCompatActivity {
    private int count = MainActivity.playerCount;
    private Button[] playerButtons = new Button[count];
    //private LinearLayout playerRevealmentLayout;
    //private LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_revealment);

        /*playerRevealmentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.playerRevealmentLayout);

        for (int i = 0; i < playerButtons.length; i++) {
            playerButtons[i] = new Button(this);
            playerButtons[i].setText("Player " + i); //Change to actual names
            playerRevealmentLayout.addView(playerButtons[i], lp);
        }*/
        Toast.makeText(PlayerRevealment.this, MainActivity.players.length, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I have tried making them public and static, and I referenced them with MainActivity.playerCount and MainActivity.players[i], but this just resulted in the app crashing. Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance for any help. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy..Change MainActivity ...

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText[] playersEditText = new EditText[10];

// Use String array to store Player's names.
private String[] players=new String[10];
private int playerCount = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    playersEditText[0] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player0);
    playersEditText[1] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player1);
    playersEditText[2] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player2);
    playersEditText[3] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player3);
    playersEditText[4] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player4);
    playersEditText[5] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player5);
    playersEditText[6] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player6);
    playersEditText[7] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player7);
    playersEditText[8] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player8);
    playersEditText[9] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player9);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            playerCount = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                String name = playersEditText[i].getText().toString();

                if (!(name.equals(""))) {
                    playerCount++;
                    players[playerCount] = name;
                }
            }

            if (playerCount < 5)
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You need at least 5 players " + playerCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else {
                Intent intent=new Intent(this,PlayerRevealment.class);
                intent.putExtra("yourCountKey",playerCount);
                intent.putExtra("yourArrayKey",players);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
}
 }
```

and access your data in second activity as following..

```
public class PlayerRevealment extends AppCompatActivity {

//Use playerArray here.
private Player[] players = new Player[10];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_revealment);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int playerCount = intent.getIntExtra("yourCountKey", 5);
    String[] playerNames = intent.getStringArrayExtra("yourArrayKey");
    // Now create your players array.
    for (int i = 0; i < playerNames.length; i++) {
        players[i] = new Player(playerNames[i]);
    }
      //Do your stuff..
}
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it still crashes when I move to the second activity. Any ideas?

Comment: It crashes because the class Player not implements android.io.Parcelable.

Comment: and I suggest you to only pass String array , because you are just collecting player's names in MainActivity..I will edit my answer for that.

Comment: I implemented Parcelable, but it still crashes. Also, I need to use a Player array instead of a String array because there's other information I will add to the Player class. I'm just not wanting to address that until this issue is fixed.